# Getting error in logs after doing CMS DB restore for WEB 8 in our application

Tags: dxa, web8, keyword

Getting below warning in logs after doing CMS DB restore for WEB 8 in our application. The app fails to load and gives a blank page. I am, however, NOT able to find this particular keyword in any of the environments!!

Please, could you suggest what could be the issue?

> 2018-06-18 08:12:30,068 WARN  c.s.d.m.s.p.e.PageModelExpander - Keyword 3846 in publication 19 cannot be found, is it published?

Comment: Error indicating one of the page used keyword (tcm:19-3846-1024), Not able to expand the keyword details during the ViewModel build. you have mentioned that item does not exist in CM, Maybe that item removed from CM, not republished that page from CM to CD, still that Page json has that keyword reference. Please edit your question and update bit more detail about the CMS  DB restore what it's exactly, I'm suspecting CM and CD DBs not in sync.

Comment: @Velmurugan Thanks for the quick response. Looks like the keywords were present but we were not ablt to get them via SDL search. After much deep digging, we found the relevant ones and published the respective categories, which fixed the issue!

Comment: Please Answer your own Question, in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the keywords were present but we were not able to get them via SDL search. After much deep digging, we found the relevant ones and published the respective categories, which fixed the issue!